# Using Pub/Sub for Google Cloud Storage with GKE

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE application that currently is driven by Notifications from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I want to convert this node.js application to be triggered instead by PubSub notifications. I've been crawling through Google documentation pages most of the day, and do not have a clear answer. I see some python code that might do it, but it's not helping much.

The code as it is currently written is working - an image landing in my GCS bucket triggers a notification to my GKE pod(s), and my function runs. Trying to understand what I need to do inside my function to subscribe to a Pub/Sub topic to trigger the processing.  Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you describe what is your current implementation? I don't understand how Cloud Storage can call a GKE pod without PubSub push subscription.

Comment: We are currently using Object notifications, as described here:  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Answer (score 2):

*Firstly thanks, I didn't know the notification capability of GCS!!*

The principle is close but you use PubSub as intermediary. Instead of notify directly your application with a watchbucket command, you notif a [PubSub topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications).

From there, the notifications arrive in PubSub topic, now you have to create a subscription. 2 types are possible:

- Push: you specify an HTTP URL that is called with a POST request, and the body contain the notification message.
- Pull: your application need to create a connection with the PubSub subscription and to read the messages.

---

Pro and cons

- Push requires an authentication from the PubSub push subscription to your application. And if you use internal IP, you can't use this solution (URL endpoint must be publicly accessible). The main advantage is the scalability and the simplicity of the model.
- Pull require an authentication of the subscriber (here your application) and thus, even if your application is privately deployed, you can use Pull subscription. Pull is recommended for high throughput but require higher skill in processing, concurrency/multi-threading programming. You don't scale on request rate (as with Push model) but according to the number of message that you read. And you need to acknowledge manually the messages.

---

Data model is [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#format). Your pubsub message is [like that](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

```
{
  "data": string,
  "attributes": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "messageId": string,
  "publishTime": string,
  "orderingKey": string
}
```

The attributes are discribed in the documentation and the payload (base64 encoded, be carefull) has [this format](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource-representations). Very similar of what you get today.

So, why the attributes? Because you can use the [filter feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering) on PubSub to create subscription with only a subset of messages.

---

You can also shiht gears and use [Cloud Event](https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/events/anthos/quickstart#initialize-events) (base on Knative events) if you use Cloud Run for Anthos in your GKE cluster. Here, the main advantage is the portability of the solution, because the messages are compliant with Cloud Event format and not specific to GCP.

Comment: Thanks Guilllaume, I'll dig into this and see what I can make happen. As to the notifications, you're welcome, but Google recommends we use Pub/Sub, and we have found that under moderately heavy load, the notifications can get lost. That is the main reason we want to move to pub/sub.